# Off-setting a single character in a text box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, font

I am attempting to offset an ESRI character (the bird in the image) to be bottom-alignment with Location X. Is there any type of formatting tag that might allow me to shift the character upward? I already tried Superscript and it shrunk the symbol down too much.
The input text is below:

```
<BOL>Location X</BOL><FNT name="ESRI Environmental &amp; Icons" size="30"> )</FNT>
Disease Y
Total Avian Cases: 12,345
<FNT size="8">Since:  01 JAN 2016 </FNT>
```

[image: Textbox input]

Comment: superscript with a larger font size?

Comment: Superscript causes the symbol to shrink down. It also shifts the symbol up too high (pretty much the opposite of the current position).

Comment: Have you considered having the Text Box contain only the text, and then adding a separate graphic element that you position precisely where you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was a little unorthodox, but it got the desired result without requiring an additional graphic element to manually offset an icon--this product gets updated very frequently.

1) I went to http://www.myscriptfont.com/ and downloaded the custom font creation form

2) I opened the pdf file in Adobe (any illustrator would work), then I added .png silhouette images in the character boxes. I made sure to offset them (a little on the +y side).

3) Upload the form back to the myscriptfont site and download the resulting .ttf file-- I named it "TreeBird1".

4) Drop the file into my fonts folder on the C: drive.

5) Restart arc, then just use formatting tags to activate the custom font. In this case, a bird was equivalent to the letter "D" in my new file.

```
<BOL>Country X</BOL>
Bird Disease <FNT name="TreeBird1" size="16"> D</FNT>
Total Avian Cases: <BOL><CLR red="233">15</CLR></BOL> (<BOL><CLR red="233">+3</CLR></BOL>)
<FNT size="8">Since:  01 JAN 2016 </FNT>
```

[image]

Pretty much every silhouette image on the internet can now be added in-line to ArcMap without an offset issue. Birds, trees, mushrooms, anything.